# Cant find Bing image search api in azure console

Tags: azure

I am totally lost in the azure console. I set up an account. But still it asks me if I want to have an account although Im logged in.
My main problem is, I cant find the subscription key for Bing image search API. I could find it as 7 day trail with a demo key and it works. But cant find how to subscribe to the service. I tried via cognitive services but this keys do not work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a New Bing Search service from the Azure portal. Goto your portal and type Bing search in the search bar,

[image]

Once the resource is created, you can get the keys by navigating as follows,

[image]

Comment: Ty, it works! It confused me that the docus tell to subrcibe cognitive service.